# NSMenuBar mouse down notification?

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

i'm trying to find notification/way to check if NSStatusItem from NSStatusBar (System wide bar) was clicked.

Does anybody knows how to achive this ?

Thanks

**EDITED 20120111**

I meant "any" item from whole status bar.

Answer (score 1):

do something like:

```
statusItem.target = self;
statusItem.action = @selector(mouseDown:);
statusItem.sendActionOn = NSLeftMouseDownMask; // try without this at first - i can't remember what the default it so you probrably don't need it
```

then:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"click click");
}
```